# How to deal with duplicates in red-black trees?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, red-black-tree

So I've been(so far unsuccessfully) trying to make my red-black tree implementation work consistently with duplicates, but it seems to always be missing that small something, so here I am.

I tried make the tree lean to one side, but It didn't seem to balance it properly(from the color perspective).I'd like to ask how should one go about adding duplicates to a red-black tree?(apart obviously making the node fat, holding or pointing to duplicate key values).

Not really looking for a code review, more interested in suggestions. So basically the methods(taken from Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition) I use for insert and balancing are these(while rotations are pretty obvious):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go for the obvious one and hold a list of values for each key. Keys are meant to be unique. How are you going to look the nodes up anyways?

Comment: I would choose to not add separate nodes for each value of a key, but instead bundle them in a single node (in a list or sth). R-B trees aren't really designed for data structures which support duplicates, but rather sets.

Comment: You can get better answers if you tell us what it is that you think it's missing. An example would work wonders.

Comment: @Sorin Wanted a more general answer, since, as mentioned in a comment below, I'm working with external memory only, so the code would be quite a pain to look through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the pseudo-code you wrote here, it is completely agnostic to the question of whether keys are duplicate or not. The code here only looks at the result of *comparing* keys, and doesn't care if they are identical or not. In fact, unique-key implementations need to go out of their way to make `RB-Insert` detect duplicate keys. The data structure doesn't care about this naturally, and the algorithms and proofs hold whether there are duplicate keys or not. If you implemented these functions correctly, it should work as is.

I also disagree with the comments advising you to hold what you call "fat nodes". Holding multiple keys is the common implementation of C++'s [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), for example. Not that from a computational complexity point of view, say that you have altogether *n* keys, but each *k* are a multiple. Using the "efficient" fat node version, the complexity of the basic find operation will be *Θ(log(n / k)) = Θ(log(n) - log(k))*; using the multiple key version, the complexity will be *Θ(log(n))*. In real life cases, probably *k << n*, which means that the relative difference is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, seems I have something working wrong then. I have the tedious assignment of only working with external memory(can't load the tree to memory) so It's screwing me over plenty.

Also, isn't the pseudo-code right-leaning, since the else statement in insert will be the one to always catch the equals case?

Comment: The tree will transiently be right leaning, but the call to `RB-Insert-Fixup` will make it balanced again. Think of it this way: if you insert the keys *1, 2, 3, 4, ...* (no two of which are identical), does the tree become imbalanced? Each key will originally be inserted along the rightmost spine of the tree. It just won't stay there necessarily following enough fixups.

Comment: Ahh, got it, that's most likely why my lean wasn't working , thank you for the help, appreciate it.